# How to arrange the color of tab in a format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have got a task to arrange the color of tab.The first tab contains a light color, the second color contains little bit darker than first and third is darker than second etc.{Gradient Color}
For that i have the given code

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris </p>
    <p>Duis cursus.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

How can I do this using jquery?[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5zfyU/)

Comment: Why not apply the color just in CSS?

Comment: but when i add a new tab.wat to do?

Comment: You could look into using Less for this I think. With less you can speciofy a colour +/- 10% etc. So you could dpo it programmatically and as as many colors as you liked.

Comment: You mean change color of font?

Comment: @Kasyx- I want to changing the color of .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zfyU/3/
The key is to add class to `li` elements:

`class="gradient_me"`

And then, after creating tab, just `each` them all and depend color on `index`. For example:

```
$('.gradient_me').each( function(index) {
      var color = 255-index*75;
      $(this).css('color', 'rgb('+color+', 0, 0)');
});
```

Comment: nope, there are 3 tabs with 3 different colors: `rgb('125', '125', '125')`, `rgb('100', '100', '100')`, `rgb('75', '75', '75')`

Comment: I can't get you.Pls put that in your demo

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/5zfyU/3/ now its easy to see, next tab color is darker.

Comment: What happens when you add tabs?  A 4th tab will make your color value negative.  Dinging you with a -1 until you make this work for all number of tabs, since the OP did mention adding tabs in his comments.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein its just idea. With more tabs, you should for example scale values in defined range. For example: `step= parseInt(range/tabs)`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what you want is to understand the [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color model.  The nice thing about HSL is that it lets you change the lightness of your color simply by modifying one of the variables - and that CSS accepts HSL (or HSLA if you want alpha) as a valid color specifier.

What you need to do is start with a given color, preferably in HSL format.  (There are plenty of converters from RGB to HSL, if necessary, just Google "convert RGB to HSL".)  Once you have the Hue and Saturation, linearly interpolate the lightness value for the number of tabs you have.  (Instead of binding the lightness between 0 and 1, I'd bind it between something like 0.25 and 0.75, so you won't have extremes that will make it hard to see against your background.)

Here's the working code I made:

```
$(function () {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});

var input_prefix = "hsl(0, 100%, ";
var li = $("#tabs li a");
var count = li.length;

if (count == 1) {
    // This is just here for thoroughness - my algorithm depends on at least 2 tabs
    li.css("color", input_prefix + "50%)");
} else {
    li.each(function (index) {
        // You want from lighter to darker, so start with the highest Lightness
        // 75 is what I'm setting as the upper percentage, and it's 50 percent from 
        // the start of 75 to the end of 25, divided over the number of elements.
        var value = 75 - (index * 50 / count);
        var color = input_prefix + value + "%)";
        $(this).css("color", color);
    });
}
```

Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zfyU/4/) of the solution.